# my mysql result set is duplicating?why

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

im doing this query on mysql, but its giving me duplicate results sets:

this is my query:

```
SELECT u.username, u.picture, m.id, m.user_note, m.reply_id, m.reply_name, m.dt, m.votes_up
FROM user u, notes m
WHERE m.topic_id =14
ORDER BY m.dt DESC
```

i dont understand why its doing it? please help :))

EDIT: table schema

```
notes{id, user_id, topic_id, user_note, reply_id, reply_name, votes_up, dt}
user {user_id, username, password, email, full_name, picture, date_join}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no join condition on your where clause. Its create a Cartesian product of your results I would guess.

---

So you have two tables when you select from two tables it gives you the [Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the results sets or all the rows in A X all the rows in B.  What you need to do is link the two tables together ie to relate them. `select * from User as U,Notes as N where U.ID = N.UserID` Then add your other constraints.

Comment: but i don't want to select only one user, i want all the users notes. i still dont get whatyou mean im still a newbie to this

Comment: only if i link it with the topics table, i.e t.topic_id =n.topic_id, but that would be mkaing the database engine work harder, when i already have topic_id value that i needed :)) if you get what i mean

Comment: you won't get only one user, you'll end up with all notes and their user selected on one line per user/note combination.  to get only one user you'd have to do something like u.id = 1.

Comment: You want all the user information for every user linked to topicid 14 is that right?

Comment: oh my god im so stupid, yeh thats true, sorry sorry, yeh fixed it, i need to wake up and smell the coffee sireous? wow thanks you guys +upvote for me